# Android Mono List view

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Hi Hope some one can help me i'm new to Mono and Android
i can do the ListActivity with code
eg. activity.cs code looks like this

```
     [Activity(Label = "My Activity")]
public class TestScreen : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
```

string[] values = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};

```
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; ++i)
        {
         list.Add(values[i]);
          }


         ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,  list);
```

and my result is the ListActivity in a single screen

### like this

Cant post images :(

### Single Screen With the list

What i would like to achieve is 
i would like to create a Layout 
and then pull the list into the layout 
like this lest call this layout custom.axml
not sure how to link the data to my layout

Cant post images :(
this layout consist of 3 objects

1. Button
2. ListView --- want to populate the list view with the list
3. TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your layout at the bottom, minus the XML header.

To make it work, you have to modify your OnCreate method to load your listview this way.. since you have more items in your view than just the List for your activity.

```
SetContentView (Resource.Layout.YourLayoutFileName);
ourlist = FindViewById<ListView> (Android.Resource.Id.List);
ourlist.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,  list);



<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<Button
     android:id="@+id/yourbutton"
     android:layout_width="300dip"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="Your Text"/>
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dip"
    android:textSize="20dip" />
```

Comment: Hi Thanks i'm going to test this in the morning and see what happens will give feedback thanks

Comment: No problem. : )  It also cut off the closing </LinearLayout> for some reason.

Comment: Added a line I forgot. : ) Just to load your xml layout in the ListActivity. Should be done after base.OnCreate(bundle);

Comment: Worked 100% i now understand now how to populate to the Presentation layer THANKS !

Comment: No problem at all. Glad to help. : )

Comment: can i ask you something else 
ive tried and sorry im realy new to this
if i click on the list how do i change the TextView with some new text ?

Comment: Hm.  In your list activity, you can make things happen by putting code into OnListItemClick. If you type as if to add the method. Make sure you make it as a protected override void and then pick it from the list that will show in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio. Sorry, in a vehicle traveling to CA right now.